# How to avoid multiple rerenders in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom Slider Input component and block with value that is based on value of Slider Input. Slider Input has onChange calback triggers on every change of value in component. I want change value in div while moving the slider without debouncing or throttling, but every setValue triggers rerender of component. That's why slider does not move smoothly and component slows down. How can I solve this problem?

**Simplified code**

```
export const Component = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

  const handleChange = value => setValue(value)

  const calculate = () => {
    // some calculations with value
    return value
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SliderInput value={value} onChange={handleChange} />

      <div>{calculate()}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

[interface example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrqH0.png)

**UPDATE**

Code of SliderInput. It's really big and unoptimized

```
export const SliderInput = ({
  label,
  info,
  tooltip,
  disabled,
  size = 'lg',
  type = 'currency',
  currency = 'RUB',
  period = 'years',
  step = 1,
  min = 1,
  max = 100,
  percent,
  isRange = false,
  handleDistance = 10,
  onBeforeChange,
  onChange,
  onAfterChange,
  value,
  readOnly,
  marks,
  borders,
  className,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(value || min)
  const [inputValue, inputHandler] = useState(state)
  const [rangeInput, setRangeInput] = useState(value || [min, max])
  const [rangeState, setRangeState] = useState(value || [min, max])
  const suffixes = {
    years: ['год', 'года', 'лет'],
    months: ['месяц', 'месяца', 'месяцев'],
    days: ['день', 'дня', 'дней'],
  }
  const sliderProps = {
    borders,
    borderType: type,
    period,
    marks,
    disabled: disabled || readOnly,
    min,
    max,
    step,
    handleDistance,
    isRange,
    size,
    onBeforeChange,
    onChange,
    onAfterChange,
  }
  const inputProps = {
    label,
    info,
    tooltip,
    disabled,
    size,
    readOnly,
  }
  const declOfNum = (number, titles) => {
    const cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
    return titles[number % 100 > 4 && number % 100 < 20 ? 2 : cases[number % 10 < 5 ? number % 10 : 5]]
  }

  const getSuffix = _value => {
    const value = typeof _value !== 'number' ? clean(_value, 'from get suffix') : _value
    return type === 'currency' ? currencySymbols[currency] : declOfNum(value, suffixes[period])
  }

  const getMask = value => {
    return createNumberMask({
      prefix: '',
      suffix: ` ${getSuffix(value)}`,
      thousandsSeparatorSymbol: ' ',
    })
  }

  const handler = (value, source) => {
    const _value = typeof value !== 'number' && clean(value, 'from usual handler')
    let output
    if (source === 'slider') {
      output = value
      setState(value)
    }
    if (source === 'input') {
      if (_value > max) {
        output = max
        setState(max)
        inputHandler(max)
      } else if (_value < min) {
        output = min
        setState(min)
      } else {
        output = _value
        setState(_value)
      }
    }
    inputHandler(value)
    onChange && onChange(output)
  }

  const handleRange = (value, source) => {
    let output
    if (source === 'slider') {
      output = value
      setRangeState(value)
      setRangeInput(value)
    }
    if (source === 'input-left') {
      const _value = clean(value)
      if (_value >= min && _value <= max) {
        output = [_value, rangeState[1]]
        setRangeState(output)
        setRangeInput(output)
      }
    }
    if (source === 'input-right') {
      const _value = clean(value)
      if (_value >= min && _value <= max) {
        output = [rangeState[0], _value]
        setRangeState([rangeState[0], _value])
        setRangeInput([rangeInput[0], _value])
      }
    }
    output && onChange && onChange(output)
  }

  const handleBlur = e => {
    const value = clean(e.target.value)
    value < min ? handler(min, 'slider') : value > max ? handler(max, 'slider') : null
  }

  const handleRangeBlur = (e, source) => {
    const value = clean(e.target.value)
    if (source === 'left') {
      const minLeft = rangeState[1] - handleDistance * step
      value > minLeft && handleRange([minLeft, rangeState[1]], 'slider')
      value < min && handleRange([min, rangeState[1]], 'slider')
    } else {
      const minRight = rangeState[0] + handleDistance * step
      value > max && handleRange([rangeState[0], max], 'slider')
      value < minRight && handleRange([rangeState[0], minRight], 'slider')
    }
  }

  return (
    <WrapperSlider className={className} size={size}>
      {!isRange ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Input
            {...inputProps}
            mask={getMask(inputValue)}
            value={typeof inputValue === 'number' || inputValue === '' ? inputValue : clean(inputValue)}
            onChange={e => {
              handler(e.target.value, 'input')
            }}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            {...rest}
          />
          <StyledRangeSlider {...sliderProps} value={state} onChange={value => handler(value, 'slider')} />
          {percent && (
            <Percent>
              <Text size={size}>{percent}</Text>
            </Percent>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Input
            {...inputProps}
            mask={getMask(rangeInput[0])}
            value={rangeInput[0]}
            onChange={e => {
              handleRange(e.target.value, 'input-left')
            }}
            onBlur={e => handleRangeBlur(e, 'left')}
            {...rest}
          >
            <InnerInputWrapper size={size}>
              <Input
                size={size}
                readOnly={readOnly}
                disabled={disabled}
                mask={getMask(rangeInput[1])}
                value={rangeInput[1]}
                onChange={e => {
                  handleRange(e.target.value, 'input-right')
                }}
                onBlur={e => handleRangeBlur(e, 'right')}
                {...rest}
              />
            </InnerInputWrapper>
          </Input>
          <StyledRangeSlider {...sliderProps} value={rangeState} onChange={value => handleRange(value, 'slider')} />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </WrapperSlider>
  )
}
```

Comment: You'll have to use `debounce`, without that your handler will get called on every change. 
That will make your component slow.

Comment: Can you add the slider code as well?

Comment: If I use debounce component will delay render of transformed value while moving the slider, right? But I want to see changes without delays.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

export const Component = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

  const handleChange = useCallback((value) => {setValue(value)}, []); 
  
  const calculate = useCallback(() => {
      // some calculations with value
    return value
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <>
      <SliderInput value={value} onChange={handleChange} />

      <div>{calculate()}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Your component will re-render whenever there is a change in reference.

In the example above, whenever slider changes, the handleChange and calculate function references are changed, which will cause your component to re render.

In this case, you can use "useCallback" hook to avoid changing the function reference. Refer https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: I poorly understood how to use useCallback in this case. could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @AlekseiIvasiuta added an example with your simplified code. In the above case, it will re-render only when the value changes and not each time the reference of calculate/handleChange reference changes